Conceptualizing a probability solution
While studying for a probability actuary exam, I came across this problem:
"An insurance policy will reimburse only one claim per year.  For a random policyholder, there is a 20% probability of no loss in the next year, in which case the claim amount is 0.  If a loss occurs in the next year, the claim amount is normally distributed with a mean of 1000 and standard deviation of 400.  Calculate the median claim amount in the next year for a random policyholder."
Finding the value of $x$ satisfying $.2 + .8*P(X\leq x) = .5$ where $X$ is normal was presented as the solution.  However, scaling $P(X \leq x)$ by .8 and then adding .2 to it was presented in a hand-wavy way. Those moves "make sense," but not in a way that I can fit into my understanding basic probability concepts.  That's what I'd like some help on.
The closest I've come is an application of the total probability law that sums the four combinations of loss events and amounts and sets it equal to .5.
Let $C$ and $L$ be the event of a claim and loss, respectively, and $X$ the loss amount, normally distributed. We know $P(L) = .8$ and $P(L^{c}) = .2$. Then
$$\begin{align}P(C) &= P(L)P(X\leq 0 |L) + P(L^{c})P(X\leq 0 |L^{c}) + P(L)P(X\leq x |L) + P(L^{c})P(X\leq x |L^{c}) = .5 \\
                    & = .8 \cdot 0~ +~.2\cdot 1~+.8P(X\leq x |L) + .2 \cdot 0 =.5\\
                    & = .2 + .8P(X\leq x |L) = .5
\end{align}$$
Any comments or suggestions on how to constructively conceptualize this solution would be greatly appreciated!

Perhaps it would make  more intuitive sense if you imagined that each policy holder draws a random claim value from that distribution, then they toss a fair five sided die and, if they get a $1$, they claim $0$ and if they get anything else they claim the value they drew.  Thus the expected value of their claim is $.8\times x$, if they drew $x$.

Thank you!  That's helpful!

As another way to gain intuition:  try a discrete version.  Now, if a claim is filed, it is one of the three values $(600, 1000, 1400)$ with probabilities $(.125,.75, .125)$.  You can confirm that the mean is $1000$ and $\sigma=200$ just as in your normal case.  Then the possible claims are $(0, 600,1000,1400)$ with probabilities $(.2, .8\times .125, .8\times .75, .8\times .125)$.

Even better.  Thanks!
